# How to get Container Managed DataSource Object in Structs Action

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

I am new to use Struts 2 Framework.

I need to use DataSource Object in Struts Action Class.
My platform is Tomcat 8 (Servlet 3.1) and I set Resource in context.xml.

I can inject Container managed DataSource Object in a servlet by using @Resource annotation.

I'd tried in this way.
I create a ServletContextListener and inject DataSource in this listener.
I set this datasource to application scope object in contextInitialized method.

```
@WebListener
public class ResourceListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Resource(name="jdbc/skill_db")
    private DataSource ds;

    public ResourceListener() { }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("Datasource", ds);
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("dbConfigStream", sce.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/database.properties"));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { }

}
```

After that I access application scope and get this datasource from Struts Action methods.

```
public String welcome() {

    Map<String, Object> application = ActionContext.getContext().getApplication();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) application.get("Datasource");
    InputStream conf = (InputStream) application.get("dbConfigStream");

    Model<Employee> empModel = new BaseModel<Employee>(Employee.class, 
        Employee::convert, ds, conf);
    list = empModel.getAll();

    return "welcome";
}
```

My question are :

1. Can I get DataSource object in a structs action object?
2. Is this way that I tried a correct way in struts?

Comment: Why don't you inject it into action?

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried resource injection in Structs Action class. But it doesn't work. The datasource object was null when I checked by debugging mode.

Comment: Take a look at S2 cdi plugin: https://struts.apache.org/docs/cdi-plugin.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks! I will try it. I also need to use DI in Struts 2. But I don't want to use spring or weld in this project. Thank you!

Comment: For spring there is S2 spring plugin, but if you don't want to use spring then cdi is a way to go. After you solve you problem you can come back, answer your question yourself and accept it to help future visitors.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes I will. If there is only two ways, I will choose CDI rather than Spring DI. I will try in CDI way. After knowing the answer I will update my question.

Answer (score 3):

I tried my requirements by Struts2-CDI Plugin
By using CDI I can inject my dependencies.

**1. I edit POM of my project as follow.**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-cdi-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**2. As I used Tomcat I need to add this codes to context.xml and web.xml to use CDI.**

**2.1 context.xml**

```
<Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container"
    type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" 
    factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
```

**2.2 web.xml**

```
  <resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
```

**3. Produce Datasource**

Inject directly DataSource object and ServletContext into ResourceProducer class. So that I don't need listener class to set DataSource to application scope and also don't need to access indirectly to servlet context object.

Using CDI make free the limitations of Struts.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ResourceProducer {

    @Resource(name="jdbc/skill_db")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Inject
    private ServletContext servletContext;


    @Produces
    @DbResourse
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        return datasource;
    }

    @Produces
    @DbConfiguration
    public InputStream getConfiguration() {
        return servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/database.properties");
    }

}
```

**4. Inject DataSource at Model Producer**

```
@Inject
@DbResourse
private DataSource ds;
@Inject
@DbConfiguration
private InputStream dbConfig;

@Produces
@DataModel(Employee.class)
public Model<Employee> getEmployeeModel() {
    return new BaseModel<Employee>(Employee.class, Employee::convert, ds, dbConfig);
}
```

**5. Inject Model at Struts 2 Action Class**

```
@Inject
@DataModel(Employee.class)
private Model<Employee> empModel;

public String welcome() {

    list = empModel.getAll();

    return "welcome";
}
```

Comment: Cheer ! bro ... I am glad to your success. This may be helpful to other guys who are willing as you.